# Assigning a custom icon to a Mac desktop element

Tags: java, macos, icons, shortcut, filewriter

I am writing an application in Swing that involves creating an *Internet shortcut* on the desktop for a particular site. It works fine in Windows. Mac allows me to create the shortcut, but does not allow me to assign it my custom icon. How can I assign an icon to the URL file on a Mac programmatically?

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class MACutils {
    private MACutils() {
    }

    public static void createInternetShortcutOnDesktop(String name,
      String target, String icon) throws IOException {
        String username = System.getProperty("user.home");
        System.out.println(username);
        String path = username + "/Desktop" + "/" + name + ".URL";
        createInternetShortcut(name, path, target, icon);
    }

    public static void createInternetShortcut(String name, String where,
      String target, String icon) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(where);
        fw.write("[InternetShortcut]\n");
        fw.write("URL=" + target + "\n");

        if (!icon.equals("")) {
            fw.write("IconFile=" + icon + "\n");
              // icon has the path to my .png/.icns image
            fw.write("IconIndex=0");
        }
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file with a `.webloc` file extension, then write a plist to the file with the URL, i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>URL</key>
    <string>http://hasseg.org/setWeblocThumb/#scmRepoInfo</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Writing the icon is trickier, as Mac OS X stores it in the Resource Fork.

See [example app with source in Objective-C](http://hasseg.org/setWeblocThumb/#scmRepoInfo).

Comment: hi @nekno **setweblocThumb** didnt work for me, it kept throwing up "Nothing found to launch" at the terminal although i was adding .webloc files to my desktop. 
Also, it supposedly assigns the image of the webpage that the link points to and not my custom .icns or .png file..i need to send this to my customer and i really need to have my own custom icon file..is there any other way i can do that?..